# startup.ActivityLogin has leaked window DecorView@3a9e526[ActivityLogin] that was originally added here

Tags: android-activity, dialog, alert

Here is my code, I am trying to allow the user to sign in via his Gmail id. But I am getting this error:
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTbXR.png)

Not sure what I am missing, I think I have called dismiss() at the right place. Is it the timing issue?
The app is launching fine in my phone though. I am not sure if it will crash in other devices so I want to get rid of this error.

```
    //Google Sign In
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_KEY) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);

        } catch (ApiException e) {
            if (e.getStatusCode() == 12500) {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Sign In Error! Update Google Play Service.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        showGoogleSignUpDialog();
                        storeUserInfo(user.getPhotoUrl().toString(), user.getUid(), user.getDisplayName(), user.getEmail());
                    } else {
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Sign In Failed!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void storeUserInfo(final String stringUserImage, final String stringUserID, final String stringName, final String stringEmail) {
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
            .setDisplayName(stringName)
            .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse(stringUserImage))
            .build();

    user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        firebaseFirestore.collection("UserData").document(stringUserID).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                                if (documentSnapshot.getData() != null && documentSnapshot.getData().size() > 0) {
                                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Welcome back!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(ActivityLogin.this, ActivityHome.class));
                                    finish();

                                } else {
                                    createUserData(stringUserID, stringUserImage, stringName, stringEmail);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void createUserData(String stringUserID, String stringUserImage, String stringName, String stringEmail) {
    final Map<String, Object> userDataMap = new HashMap<>();
    userDataMap.put("userName", stringName);
    userDataMap.put("userImage", stringUserImage);
    userDataMap.put("userID", stringUserID);
    userDataMap.put("userPoints", 100);
    userDataMap.put("userVerified", true);
    userDataMap.put("userEmail", stringEmail);
    userDataMap.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

    firebaseFirestore.collection("UserData").document(stringUserID).set(userDataMap)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            alertGoogleSignIn.dismiss();
                            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Welcome!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(ActivityLogin.this, ActivityHome.class).putExtra("canShowCoinCredit", true));
                            finish();
                        }
                    }, 3000);
                }
            });
}

private void showGoogleSignUpDialog() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Signing in");
    alert.setMessage("Please hold on while we process...");
    alert.setCancelable(false);
    alertGoogleSignIn = alert.create();
    alertGoogleSignIn.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
Generate the onStop() override method and transfer your startactivity as shown below. The finish() method you have already specified will invoke the onStop() override method then your activity should be started.

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() { 
       super.onStop();
       startActivity(new Intent(ActivityLogin.this, ActivityHome.class).putExtra     ("canShowCoinCredit", true));
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's going to resolve it. Basically the issue I am facing is while signing in with Gmail, it doesn't work. 
It works flawlessly in the release apk but when I build the apk bundle and upload it to the playstore it doesn't work.
Here is the application: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.isshin.otakushinbun
Please try to sign in with Gmail and you would know what issue I am facing.

Comment: And here is the release apk. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KC9bFtzGA2PGOcZXlkmNlm_P323Jaut3/view?usp=sharing
In this the sign in process works but it doesn't work in the play store version for some reason.

Comment: Hi, I experienced similar behavior. I initially concentrated on dismissing all possible dialogs (including declaring them transient) without success. In the end, I realized that I was calling an intent from within an alert dialog box. The logic being that an activity is being started from within a dialog box that has not been dismissed.  Try checking other parts of the code if you could have done this

Comment: No the only dialog box I have is the googlealertdialog and it is already there above as you can, I haven't called any other intent from within that alert box.
If you don't mind, can you take a look at my login.java file?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred because alertGoogleSignIn dialog is not dismissed before intent to next screen

Need to dismiss `alertGoogleSignIn` before `startIntent`

Please add `alertGoogleSignIn.dismiss()` in following function

```
 private void storeUserInfo(final String stringUserImage, final String stringUserID, final String stringName, final String stringEmail) {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                .setDisplayName(stringName)
                .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse(stringUserImage))
                .build();

        user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            firebaseFirestore.collection("UserData").document(stringUserID).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
alertGoogleSignIn.dismiss();  // dismiss dialog here                                  
if (documentSnapshot.getData() != null && documentSnapshot.getData().size() > 0) {
                                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Welcome back!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        startActivity(new Intent(ActivityLogin.this, ActivityHome.class));
                                        finish();

                                    } else {
                                        createUserData(stringUserID, stringUserImage, stringName, stringEmail);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: But the alertGoogleSignIn dialog doesn't even show up when I try to sign in with the Gmail option.
Here is the link to the app, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.isshin.otakushinbun
It doesn't work in the playstore version but it works flawlessly in the apk release version: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KC9bFtzGA2PGOcZXlkmNlm_P323Jaut3/view?usp=sharing